# Flexdashboard Shiny - output not showing the complete output after knitting

Tags: r, shinydashboard

When I knitting the following code in Flexdashboard in R Markdown file, the entire file is not giving output on the entire page, however when I run the code chunk individually it is showing the correct output.

I have tried adjusting Column {width } as well, but nothing is happening.

---

title: "By sachin"
output:
flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
orientation: columns
vertical_layout: fill

---

```
library(flexdashboard)
```

## Page 1

### Column {data-width=650}

#### Chart A

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

library(ggplot2)

df <- read.csv("data.csv")
#view(df)

df1 <- subset(df, select = c("year","dem","all_pass"))


#str(df1)


df1$dem <- as.character(df1$dem)

df1$dem = factor(df1$dem, levels = c(0,1),
                             labels = c("Democrat","Republic"))



#view(df2)

#colnames(df2)<-c("Year","Party","All Bills Passed")

df2 <-df1 %>% group_by(year,dem) %>% summarise_at(vars(all_pass),funs(sum(. , na.rm = TRUE)))

#df2 <-df1 %>% group_by(year,dem ) %>%  summarise_at(vars(all_pass),funs(sum(. , na.rm = TRUE)))

ggplot(df2, aes(x=year, fill = dem )) +  geom_area(aes(y = all_pass))+labs(y = "All Bills Passed", x = "Year", title = "Number of bills passed since 1980")
```

## Page 2

### Column {data-width=500}

#### Chart B

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

#install.packages("jtools")
library(jtools)


df <- read.csv("data.csv")


df <- filter(df, df$congress==110)

#view(df)
df3 <- subset(df, select = c(dem, all_pass,votepct))


#view(df3)


#df3 <- filter(df3, dem ==0 & dem ==1)

#view(df3)

df3$dem <- as.character(df3$dem)

df3$dem = factor(df3$dem, levels = c(0,1),
                             labels = c("Democrat","Republic"))


#view(df3)

#fit<- lm(formula = votepct~dem,df3)

ggplot(df3, aes(x=votepct,y = all_pass, fill = dem,colour = dem )) +  geom_point(aes(y = all_pass),size=3)+labs(y = "All Pass", x = "votepct", title = "Passage and Vote Pct , 110th Congress")+ geom_smooth(method="lm")





#df4 <-df3 %>% group_by(dem) %>% summarise_at(vars(all_pass),funs(sum(. , na.rm = TRUE)))


#view(df4)



#abline(fit)
#effect_plot(fit, pred = "dem",interval = TRUE, plot.points = TRUE)
#(fit, pred = votepct, interval = TRUE, plot.points = TRUE)
```

### Column {data-width=500}

#### Chart C

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

#install.packages("jtools")
library(jtools)


df <- read.csv("data.csv")


df <- filter(df, df$congress==110)

#view(df)
df5 <- subset(df, select = c(dem, all_pass,dwnom1))


#view(df5)


#df3 <- filter(df3, dem ==0 & dem ==1)

#view(df3)

df5$dem <- as.character(df5$dem)

df5$dem = factor(df5$dem, levels = c(0,1),
                             labels = c("Democrat","Republic"))


#view(df5)

fit<- lm(formula = all_pass~dwnom1,df5)

ggplot(df5, aes(x=dwnom1,y = all_pass, fill = dem,colour = dem )) +  geom_point(aes(y = all_pass),size=3)+labs(y = "All Pass", x = "DW Nominate", title = "Passage and Ideology , 110th Congress")+geom_smooth(method="lm")
```

## Page 3

### Column {data-width=650}

#### Chart D

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(plotly)
    library(dplyr)
    library(shiny)
    
    ui <- basicPage(
      h1("Total bills passed by state delegation, 110th Congress"),
      selectizeInput(inputId = "bins",
                     label = "Choose State",
                     choices = state.abb,
                     multiple = TRUE),
      plotOutput("plot")
      
    )
    
    server <- function(input, output) {
      
      df <- 
        tibble(all_pass = sample(1:500, 350),
               st_name = rep(state.abb, 7))
    
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        req(input$bins)
        df |> 
          filter(st_name %in% input$bins) |> 
          ggplot(aes(y = all_pass,x=st_name )) + 
          geom_bar(stat = "sum")
      })
    }
    
    
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Please provide us some reproducible code of the Flexdashboard. The current code is only for shiny, not for Flexdashboard.

Comment: I have mentioned the entire code of all the pages of the dashboard, the output on the last page, is not showing on the entire page.. please help